# why can my firefox extension javascript not access opener windows and not see window.name

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon

I am writing a javascript extension and having some problems I cannot figure out.

My extension is very simple, it doesn't add any GUI elements to the firefox browser.  What it does watch the mouse move around in whatever document loads in the firefox browser, and when the mouse pauses over a "term" (word, phrase, acronym) in a text-node, it creates and displays a tiny, borderless popup window that looks similar to a tooltip just above the term by calling:

```
var cw = window.open("chrome://meanings/content/clarify.html", "clarify", attr);
```

As I read the documentation, `cw.name` should be "clarify" (from the 2nd argument).  When I read  the name back with the following, it does contains the string "clarify" as it should:

```
var cwname = cw.name;  // variable cwname does contain "clarify"
```

However, running tests indicates that when the code in the instance of the extension reads:

```
var myname0 = window.name;
var myname1 = window.top.name;
var myname2 = window.document.defaultView.name;
var myname3 = window.document.defaultView.top.name;
```

... none of those variables contain the name of the window - or any other string value.

I don't get it.  I also tried adding the following lines after `window.open()` is executed:

```
cw.name = "clarify";
cw.content.name = "clarify";
```

That doesn't change anything.  Those properties can be read with code like the following and this reports the values just set (to the extension code that just set them):

```
var test_cwname0 = cw.name;
var test_cwname1 = cw.content.name;
```

The code prints these variables to the error and browser consoles, which is how I know.

---

Another similar and possibly related problem.  The `window.opener` property doesn't work either - that variable is always null which is obviously wrong, since those windows were created by `window.open()`.

BTW, calling functions to move the windows created by `window.open()` with `cw.moveTo()` work properly, so there is some degree of connection between the two windows.

Something strange is going on, and I don't understand it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can print to the Browser Console with `Components.utils.reportError`.

Comment: How are you attaching the `window.open` call to the elements in the document?

Comment: Every print statement displayed by the error console is also displayed by the browser console.  I am not attaching window.open() to any elements in the document.  Remember, my extension is javascript code, and it works on any HTML text-node content that anyone loads into the browser (plus text-node content displayed by the little windows created by my window.open() calls).  So I have code like shown in my original message in the javascript that is my extension.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: You must have more code than that. It doesn't magically know to call your window.open when mousing over things. How you're hooking up the web page to your code is very relevant as to whether it will work. Please provide the code.

Comment: Of course code doesn't magically know anything.  Every mousemove event it clears the existing timeout timer and sets a new 250ms timeout timer.  So when the timeout timer expires and calls my timeout function, that calls window.open() to create my tiny borderless windows.  The same happens if the user pauses the mouse over my little window... a new one is created, and so forth.  That works.  But to close them at the appropriate time they need to be able to control each other (or get messages from each other), and that is where I am having problems as described in my original message.

Comment: I will prepare and upload a zip file with all my extension files in it so you can see what it is and how it works.

Comment: Note: For some strange reason that I don't understand, the behavior changed (don't think I changed anything in the code except error log statements).  Anyway, now `window.content.name` within the windows created by `window.open()` do report the name assigned in the `window.open()` statement.  But `window.name` and `window.top.name` still report no name (empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you the `window.open` method does *not* assign its second parameter to the new window's properties - as per the [mdn documentation for `.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Return_value_and_parameters), the second param is only used as the name you can use in a anchor's `target` attribute so they open their links in the new window. The reference returned by the method is your only "link" to that new window you can use in js.

The `window.opener` property should still be working though, regardless. You have to be careful, though about same-domain security restrictions and whatnot (described in the specs page). Thus (from your original script) `cw.opener` should return the current window object. From a script in the new window `window.opener.cw` would thusly reference its own window object.

To control when windows are closed it's entirely possible then to have the opener window control all that - it does after all have the references to any child windows and can close them with `cw.close()` and the like.

Comment: A couple points.  After experimentation, I found the second argument to `window.open()` is assigned to `window.content.name` but not to `window.name`.  I have no idea why. ::: The problem with having the javascript extension code in the original (browser) window control the other windows is the following.  They need to be closed when the mouse passes from one created window to another (or into the main browser window), but those mouse messages only go to the window the mouse is over.  Of course, maybe there is some obscure way for this information to be passed from child -> parent -> parent?